# Are weak equivalences characterized by the homotopy fibers in an arbitrary model category?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Given a model category $\mathcal{C}$ we can define homotopy pullbacks like the *loop space*
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\Omega_x(X) & \rightarrow & *\\
\downarrow & & \;\;\downarrow_x\\
* & \overset{x}{\rightarrow} & X
\end{array}$$
or *homotopy fibers*
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\operatorname{hofib}(f) & \rightarrow & *\\
\downarrow & & \;\;\downarrow_y\\
X & \overset{f}{\rightarrow} & Y
\end{array}$$
These can be used (as is done in [Geometry of Physics, Basic Notions of Homotopy Theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometry+of+physics+--+categories+and+toposes)) to obtain a long homotopy fiber sequence (Prop. 6.95). Moreover we could potentially use $\pi_n(X,x) = [S^0,\Omega^n(X,x)]$ as definition of homotopy groups in any model category.

By definition of weak equivalence in the Quillen model structures on Topological Spaces or Simplicial Sets, a morphism is a weak equivalence, iff it induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups, which by the long homotopy fiber sequence (and assuming $f:\pi_0(X) \cong \pi_0(Y)$) is equivalent to having all homotopy fibers weakly contractible.

> Is this (or rather something along these lines) true in an arbitrary model category? In other words: Can we use the long homotopy fiber sequence(s) to detect weak equivalences?

I am aware of the *Generalized Whitehead Theorem* saying that in any model category a weak equivalence between bifibrant objects already is an homotopy equivalence. But this doesn't seem to have consequences on my question.

I must admit that I confused myself over the (sometimes subtle) differences in the Strom-Hurewicz- and the Quillen-Serre-Model structures and how to compute homotopy colimits in them. I think there might be a counterexample hidden here, as weak homotopy equivalences need not be homotopy equivalences. But I am unsure and maybe one can still generalize by considering more general fiber sequences of the form $$...\rightarrow[A,\Omega(Y)]_{*} \rightarrow[A,\operatorname{hofib}(f)]_{*} \rightarrow [A,X]_{*} \rightarrow [A,Y]_*$$
Lastly this confusion might obfuscate some obvious thing rendering this whole question nonsense, but I am of cause unable to tell and sorry for that.

Thank you for your time and considerations.

Comment: In $Top$ you need some connectivity assumptions to be able to conclude a map is a weak equivalence by looking at its homotopy fibre (consider $\{0\}\hookrightarrow\{0,1\})$.

Comment: Right. I was wondering about the right most part of the sequence, but failed to find it in my lecture notes. Anyway, connectivity shouldn’t be the problem for generalization, or is it?

Comment: I have to admit I'm a bit confused by exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @Tyrone I think the question boils down to *can we use fiber sequences to detect weak equivalences in an arbitrary model category*? (now part of the question body)

Comment: Should be no in general, I imagine that spaces with Hurewicz fibrations and cofibrations along with homotopy equivalences gives a counterexample. We have objects that are not contractible, but look like it from their homotopy groups. But of course you might just add bifibrancy and it very well could be true.

Comment: @ConnorMalin This is what I got confused about, but I think you are right. The fiber sequences agree for both model structures (Quillen equivalence), so your counterargument should work out (regarding homotopy groups). But what about testing things on a collection of fiber sequences $...[A,\Omega^n(X)]...$ indexed by a set of nice objects $\{A,A',...\}$?

Comment: Give $Top$ the trivial structure (we$=$isos, cof$=$fib$=$everything) and consider any continuous bijection which is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: I must admit I‘m a bit confused by what you mean by this...

Comment: In a non-hypercomplete $\infty$-topos there are morphisms that are isomorphisms of homotopy groups in all degrees but nonetheless not equivalences.

Comment: In the example above the pullback and homotopy pullback coincide. The homotopy fibre of $f:X\rightarrow Y$ over $y\in Y$ is $f^{-1}(y)$, which will be a point whenever $f$ is bijective. Thus the homotopy fibre cannot distinguish between $f$ being a homeomorphism ($=$we) or a continuous bijection. It can determine if $f$ is injective or surjective. Note that all loop objects are trivial. There are no nontrivial homotopy groups and the fibre sequence essentially terminates at $f^{-1}(y)$. The example is extreme but clearly you can't expect much to hold for an arbitrary model category.

Comment: This makes total sense, thanks alot! I would accept this as an answer, if you want.